# How do I install all the members in archlinux package base-devel

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I wish to install all the options in the archlinux package base-devel.

When I issue the command "sudo pacman -S --needed base-devel" I get:

```
[vagrant@archlinux ~]$ sudo pacman -S --needed base-devel
warning: file-5.40-5 is up to date -- skipping
warning: findutils-4.8.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gawk-5.1.0-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gettext-0.21-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: grep-3.6-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: gzip-1.11-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: pacman-6.0.1-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: sed-4.8-1 is up to date -- skipping
warning: sudo-1.9.7.p2-1 is up to date -- skipping
:: There are 15 members in group base-devel:
:: Repository core
   1) autoconf  2) automake  3) binutils  4) bison  5) fakeroot  6) flex  7) gcc
   8) groff  9) libtool  10) m4  11) make  12) patch  13) pkgconf  14) texinfo
   15) which

Enter a selection (default=all):
```

How can I avoid getting the interactive prompt to select which package to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `--noconfirm` to avoid interactive prompts. Note that this will select the default choice for all prompts, not just the multiple selection prompt.

`man pacman` says:

> Bypass any and all “Are you sure?” messages. It’s not a good idea to do this unless you want to run pacman from a script.

Comment: Thanks I am/was aware of the noconfirm option but wasn't sure if that would mean picking the "all" option